# Task Cancellation when app enters background

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am working on xamarin forms PCL + iOS. I want to cancel a task when it enters background. And start it all over when app enters foreground.

This is what I have tried so far.. I am not sure if my way cancels any task or what is it that is happening here?

```
async void getData()
{
bool isSuccess = await getSomeData();

if(isSuccess)
await getSomeMoreData();
}

CancellationTokenSource cts;

async Task<bool> getSomeData()
{
cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

AppEntersBackgorund += (sender,args) => { cts. cancel();});

CancellationToken token = new CancellationToken();
token = cts.token;

await Task.Run(() => {
token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
isSuccess = ParserData(token); // parsedata also checks periodically if task is cancelled
},token); //what happens here when cancel called?

return isSuccess;
}

async void getSomeMoreData()
{
if(!cts.IsCancellationRequested)
 cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

AppEntersBackgorund += (sender,args) => { cts. cancel();});

CancellationToken token = new CancellationToken();
token = cts.token;

await Task.Run(() =>
{
token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
ParseSomeMoreData(token);
},token);

}
```

When app enters foregorund, I again call the getData() method so that i start all over again.

What happens is that, Task is not getting cancelled, rather getSomeMoreData is getting called twice ( or the no. of times the app goes from background to foreground) .

Can someone explain how I can achieve this? And what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is not a Xamarin problem, it is just a C# problem except the app's enter foreground/background events.

For the requirements you need, you should make a task manager object to implement it.

I wrote a sample code for you:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace BackGroundTask
{
    public class TaskManager
    {
        //The instance property
        private static TaskManager instance;
        public static TaskManager Instance{
            get{
                if(null == instance)
                    instance = new TaskManager();
                return instance;
            }
        }

        private bool actionTaskFreeFlag = true;//Flag for if actionTask is available or not

        private Queue<Action> taskQueue;//A queue to collect the tasks you added into the manager
        private Task scanTask;//A Task to sacn the queue
        private Task actionTask;//A task to do the current action
        private Thread actionTaskRunningThread;//Record the thread that current action is working on 

        public TaskManager()
        {
            taskQueue = new Queue<Action>();

            scanTask = new Task(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    if (actionTaskFreeFlag && taskQueue.Count > 0)//If there still something to do and the actionTask is available then do the action
                    {
                        actionTaskFreeFlag = false;
                        Action action = taskQueue.Dequeue();
                        actionTask = new Task(() => {
                            actionTaskRunningThread = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread;
                            action();
                        });
                        actionTask.Start();
                        actionTask.ContinueWith(delegate {
                            actionTaskFreeFlag = true;
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            scanTask.Start();
        }

        public void AddAction(Action action) 
        {
            taskQueue.Enqueue(action);
        }

        public void CancelCurrentTaskAndClearTaskQueue()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CancelCurrentTaskAndClearTaskQueue");
            if(null != actionTaskRunningThread)
                actionTaskRunningThread.Abort();
            taskQueue.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is a sample code for how to use it to do the stuff you want:

```
//App enter background event
AppDelegate.Instance.AppDidEnterBackground += delegate {
    TaskManager.Instance.CancelCurrentTaskAndClearTaskQueue();
};
//App enter forcenground event
AppDelegate.Instance.AppWillEnterForeground += delegate {
    if (AppDelegate.FlagForGetData)
    {
        TaskManager.Instance.AddAction(GetData);
        TaskManager.Instance.AddAction(GetMoreData);
    }
};
```

And this is the methods for testing:

```
private void GetData()
{
    AppDelegate.FlagForGetData = true;
    Console.WriteLine("Began getting data.");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    AppDelegate.FlagForGetData = false;
    Console.WriteLine("Getting data succeed.");
}

private void GetMoreData()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Began getting more data.");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    Console.WriteLine("Getting more data succeed.");
}
```

Hope it can help you.